# How to "Introduce local variable" in PyCharm

Tags: variables, ide, pycharm

I am coming from IntelliJ IDEA background and used the "Introduce local variable" feature a lot by clicking `Alt+Enter` on a non-declared-yet identifier.

Now when I am using PyCharm I can't find that functionality in `Alt+Enter` menu. How can I enable this feature in in PyCharm?

I know that Python isn't a strictly-typed language but the initial value of the variable can be i.e. `None`.